# Node Webkit - Getting Data from a text field and writing to a text file

Tags: node-webkit

I'm having problems doing something I thought was straight forward. Read the value of a input field and then write the value to a text file. I got it to work but only partially and inconsistently. What happens is, text a) gets cut off (not all the data entered in the field is written to the file) and b) spaces get added between each character so the line ends up looking like this "T H I S  IS  W H A T  Y O U R  T E X T  V A L U E"

I'm GUESSING this is an issue with text being 'chunked' but never writing all the chunks to the file and I can't explain the spacing issue, encoding maybe? Anyway heres my code:

```
//(obviously there is an html field called "a1Agent" and an object called PI)
PI.Name  = document.getElementById("a1Agent").value;
fs.writeFile("c:\\Users\\Me\\Desktop\\values.txt", PI.Name);
```

Answer (score 6):

The encoding of string you get from a input widget (after you edit it) is actually utf16le, see more here:

https://github.com/rogerwang/node-webkit/issues/1669#issuecomment-42515857

Comment: I wish I had the rep to upvote you sir, thank you. Anyone who doesn't want to follow the link, this is the solution: 

fs.writeFile("c:\\Users\\Me\\Desktop\\values.txt", '\ufeff' + PI.Name, 'utf8');